# Radio/checkbox buttons "oncheck" event when is checked/selected with javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

How to detect the moment when a radio/checkbox button is **checked with javascript**?

Ex:

```
document.getElementById("myRadioButton").checked = true
```

Is there a method to detect the state change of "myRadioButton" and atach a handler?

I need it specially for Internet Explorer 6+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found a solution, the event that triggers then radio/checkbox buttons are checked with javascript(and not only) is called **onpropertychange** in ie and **DOMAttrModified** in firefox

Comment: is there is anything which on cross browser.?